# How to update current date and time in database column in asp.net mvc code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to update ModifiedDateTime column in table as there is any change or update happen.
I created one interface

```
   public interface ITimeStampedEntity
{
    Nullable<System.DateTime> EntryDateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

In my model I wrote:

```
 public partial class MaterialType : ITimeStampedEntity
    {
    //other columns
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> EntryDateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I have code in dbcontext like below whic is getting compiled but not working.

```
 public Test_Gen3_AtlasEntities()
            : base("name=Test_Gen3_AtlasEntities")
        {
            HookSaveChanges();
        }

        private void HookSaveChanges()
        {
            (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OnSavingChanges();
            };
        }
       public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            OnSavingChanges();
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void OnSavingChanges()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                ITimeStampedEntity ts = item.Entity as ITimeStampedEntity;

                if (ts != null)
                {
                    if (item.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        ts.EntryDateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                        ts.ModifiedDateTime = ts.EntryDateTimeStamp;
                    }
                    else if (item.State == EntityState.Modified)
                    {
                        ts.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The value of ts coming as null and not going inside IF. 
Kindly tell where I'm going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your interface has `DateTime` but your concrete implementation has `DateTime?` (nullable). Make then the same types

Comment: Even after changes my ts value coming null.. see the changes I made in code.

Comment: We do not know what `ChangeTracker.Entries()` returns or what their `Entity` property is :) (and I assume your no longer getting the _does not implement interface member_ error)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I'm not getting that error but not able to update date while edit as well as Insert date while creating records. I tried to write in constructor but then it is updating both columns every time which I dont want.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I got the solution after so much attempts. I have post my answer but would like to know if there is any better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the solution for my problem. It was simple without using any interface.
I created one partial class in Model and override SaveChanges() method.

```
 public partial class DataBaseEntities : DbContext
    {
        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<ModelName>().ToList())
            {
                if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Entity.EntryDateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    entry.Entity.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

In Edit View, I added one line which will not make entrydatetimestamp field null on update.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EntryDateTimeStamp, Model.EntryDateTimeStamp = Model.EntryDateTimeStamp)
```